# Syncing multiple IDs that are potentially duplicate using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am looking to sync data in a many-to-many relationship.  I have the following:

```
Class
- id
- name

Video
- id
- src

class_videos
- class_id
- video_id
- sort_order
```

According to the docs I need to produce an array in the format of:

```
[
  10 => ['sort_order' => 100],
  11 => ['sort_order' => 200],
  21 => ['sort_order' => 300]
]
```

Where the array key is the video_id and then sync it with a Class using:

```
$class->videos()->sync($array);
```

My problem is that I want to add multiple of the same video with a different sort order.  For example:

```
[
  10 => ['sort_order' => 100],
  11 => ['sort_order' => 200],
  21 => ['sort_order' => 300],
  10 => ['sort_order' => 400]
]
```

Notice how video_id 10 is at the start and end.  With this being the array key it's impossible.

I know I can probably do this by detaching all keys and then looping through and reattaching videos one by one, but this seems cumbersome and inefficient.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem, after a while but I would like to know how you solved it?